# Azure App Service Java Web App Url Home Page Path Redirect

Tags: java, azure-webapps

I deployed a java webapp onto App Service. App service has a default url
(ntpqe-nprd--tots-as.azurewebsites.net) provided but when I enter it, it says Http 404 , No resources Found.

When I add paths after the default url:
ntpqe-nprd--tots-as.azurewebsites.net/MLT-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/migration

The webapp landing page opens up and I can access web app.

What I want to know is how to access the web app landing page with just the app service default URL: ntpqe-nprd--tots-as.azurewebsites.net

Without the subsequent paths after it.

Comment: Enter the startup command in the Portal=>Your App=>Configuration=>General Settings.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://blog.zuehlke.cloud/2020/03/simple-java-app-jar-in-azure-appservice/) for more details.

Comment: Try to add CORS if there are any connections with Azure storage or any other Azure services.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it. I can use the default Root Domain to access my landing page by writing the following line of code into my pom.xml file.

ROOT

This turns war file into ROOT.war

This will in turn allow you to access war file and subsequent landing page straight from root domain url instead of with root domain url + war package + landing page name